# "Now I am" vs. "I am now"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

Which is more correct?

> Now I am the main stakeholder...

or

> I am now the main stakeholder...

Do the intonations imply different meanings?

Comment: add "I am the main stakeholder ... now" :-)

Comment: And "I now am the main stakeholder..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither is more correct. They mean different things.

You first example can be interpreted like so:

> Now **that** I am the main stakeholder ...

Which means you are about to make a pronouncement about how things will be with you are the main stakeholder.

E.g.

> Now I am the main stake holder, all developers will have their wages halved.

As a statement by itself it can be used to mean *I am now the main stakeholder*, but you have to put emphasis on *now* and make it seem like you are marking the the moment. A similar idea would be to make a future announcement:

> From 6pm today I will be the main stake holder.

Of course, if you put a comma just after *now* you get a different meaning:

> Now, I am the main stakeholder.

This is using *now* as an interjection, it doesn't really mean anything with regard to the sentence. The rest of the sentence is just a statement explaining who you are.

Your other example

> I am now the main stakeholder.

is a statement explaining that from this moment you are the main stakeholder. This structure can be used in a triumphant way, as an exclamation, for example:

> Jensen Button is now the winner!

or in a dry factual way:

> I am now the answerer.

Comment: Making the 'dropped *that*' the main interpretation of the first example doesn't seem quite right to me.  I know I have heard people do that but I think of it as being quite colloquial and I always speak the "*that*' if I intend "Now that...".  My prefered interpretation of the first sentence would be calling attention to the *newness* of the fact:  "You're not the main stakeholder, Bob is." "Ok, Bob, You're fired. *Now* I'm the main stakeholder."

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the points made by Matt, but wanted to add the following:

If you start the sentence with a designation of time, you emphasize the time.

> Now I am the main stakeholder...

This first sentence is best used if time is somehow contextually relevant. For example:

> I used to work as a bell boy here. Now I am the main stakeholder.

In contrast, your other example emphasizes either 'I' or '(the main) stakeholder', depending on context.

> They thought I'd always stay a bell boy, but I am now the main stakeholder.

The difference is negligible, however.

Answer (score -1):

"Now I am the main stake holder."

A statement by itself it can be used to mean "I am now the main stakeholder." Without the coma, it can be use as a statement regardless of you being the main stock holder now, or in a future tense. Putting emphasis on "now" and it is marking the the moment starting now. The idea is to make a future announcement as well as a present one also.

"Now, I am the main stakeholder!"

With or without an interjection, it does really mean everything with regardless of the time, but is according to the word stated. The statement explains who you are now, and who you are in the very near future. It's a matter of how you mean and feel what you say about something you have stated.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.  You have discussed punctuation variations on the first version, not the difference between the two versions in the question, which differ in word order.